# Notification setStyle is not working in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I'm stuck in notificaion.
When I run below code under lollipop and over lollipop, it works fine.

However, if I run codes in lollipop, `setstyle()` method is not working.
I also tried with remoteviews, but it also not work.

I tried with BigPicture ,but it also doesn't work.
What did I miss? 
Please help.

```
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I tried with many devices and found that it happens in android version 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any problem except setContentText() remove it and give a try to the following :

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```